# QAF : RestTestBase().getResponse().getMessageBody() return null in wsstep

Tags: qaf

I am using QAF api common step and getting null in getMessageBody(). Also printed headers, status etc and its returning proper values.

```
        System.out.println("Status is:" + new RestTestBase().getResponse().getStatus().name());  
        System.out.println("Header is:" + new RestTestBase().getResponse().getHeaders());
        System.out.println("Body is:" + new RestTestBase().getResponse().getMessageBody());
        WsStep.responseShouldHaveValueContainsIgnoringCase(expectedvalue, jpath);
```

**Output :
Status is:OK
Header is:{CF-RAY=[708ac4150dcfa03f-SIN], ..... charset=utf-8]}
Body is:null**

I have [image: console log] to use below method to get proper response.

```
    public static void responseShouldHaveValueIgnoringCase(String expectedValue, String path) {
        Object actual = JsonPath.read(new RestTestBase().getResponse().getMessageBody(), getPath(path));
        assertThat(String.valueOf(actual), Matchers.equalToIgnoringCase(expectedValue));
    }
```

Note: I am using below version and endup with null value.
<qaf-support-ws.version>3.1.0</qaf-support-ws.version> and verified in <qaf-support-ws.version>3.0.1</qaf-support-ws.version>
Moreover, morethan 9 globals were used this steps.
JsonPath.read(new RestTestBase().getResponse().getMessageBody(), getPath(path));

Reference: https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/WsStep.java

Comment: Do you mean it works with qaf 3.0.1 but not working with 3.1.0?

Comment: @user861594, I tried with lower version and upgraded with higher version, both were not working only for getMessageBody(). Same is working fine for getHeaders() and getStatus() etc..  Almost more than 9 globals were using getMessageBody() and all getting failed.
https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/WsStep.java

Comment: make sure you are doing right request and the response returns body. Will you be able to share your request call?

Comment: Hi @user861594,
` String responseBody = new RestTestBase().getResponse().getMessageBody();
System.out.println("the body is"+responseBody);`

Comment: I have attached console log screenshot in main thread.  my sample request is 
http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso/ListOfContinentsByName
Note: My query is why below code is not returning any value. Because this issue, unable to use common  wsstep methods.
String responseBody = new RestTestBase().getResponse().getMessageBody();

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOftContinent>
  <tContinent>
    <sCode>AF</sCode>
    <sName>Africa</sName>
  </tContinent>
  <tContinent>
    <sCode>AN</sCode>
    <sName>Antarctica</sName>
  </tContinent>
  <tContinent>
    <sCode>AS</sCode>
    <sName>Asia</sName>
  </tContinent>
  <tContinent>
    <sCode>EU</sCode>
    <sName>Europe</sName>
  </tContinent>
  <tContinent>
    <sCode>OC</sCode>
    <sName>Ocenania</sName>
  </tContinent>
  <tContinent>
    <sCode>AM</sCode>
    <sName>The Americas</sName>
  </tContinent>
</ArrayOftContinent>

Comment: To validate xml value you need to use steps for xpath. Steps with jsonpath are for validating  json response body.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above using [qaf-repository-editor](https://github.com/infostretch/qaf-report#qaf-repository-editor) and it works fine without issue. For  validation step using xpath i have added following dependency in pom.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

i tried following step and it worked fine.

```
response has value "Asia" at xpath "//tContinent[sCode[contains(.,'AS')]]/sName"
```

[image: console]